# LESS contrast() function

Tags: css, webkit, less, mozilla

As you probably know LESS offers many chromatic-oriented operations (e.g.: `darken()`, `lighten()` and `mix()`) and they all work great.
Unfortunately, I can't get to work one of the theoretically coolest: the function to automatically set a colour in contrast with the one you provide.
From official LESS spec:

```
contrast(@color1, [@darkcolor: black], [@lightcolor: white], [@threshold: 43%]);
```

So, my LESS is basically provided with a background variable that can vary a lot (I'm working on theme-based website) and its text colour should adapt.

```
   &.popup{
      .body{
         background-color: @popupBg;
         color: contrast(@popupBg, [@darkcolor: black], [@lightcolor: white], [@threshold: 43%]);
      }
   }
```

When inspecting the output code in the console, I can see the function not properly parsed (Chrome notifies the error, Firefox just hides it). I also tried the simplified version which is just `color: contrast(@popupBg);` and had no luck.

Has anybody used this before? I've been using LESS for quite a lot now and this is the first time it gives me problems.

Comment: Just a quick note: [] is notation for optional arguments

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The square brackets denote optional arguments and shouldn't appear in your code. Check out the LESS function reference and its [documentation on contrast](http://lesscss.org/functions/#color-operations-contrast), it has an example on how to use `contrast` correctly:

```
Example:

contrast(#aaaaaa)
contrast(#222222, #101010)
contrast(#222222, #101010, #dddddd)

Output:

#000000 // black
#ffffff // white
#dddddd
```

So your code should read:

```
color: contrast(@popupBg, black, white, 43%);
```

On the other hand, are you sure that `@popupBg` is defined?

Check out [this jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ZfNnc/2/) for a demo.

Comment: I tried, but in the console I get the whole expression stricken through (= error) as output.
The variable is properly defined as the background is actually correctly read by the browser :\

Comment: I see it is actually working...this is utterly puzzling.
Maybe my PHP compiler is to blame? Anyway, I'm glad to know this error is not on LESS' side. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

you can use like:

```
contrast(@popupBg, lighten(black, 12%), darken(white, 12%));
```